# Google API (gapi.js) in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need some help getting the Google API javascript library (taken from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) running inside Lightning Web Components so I can do an OAuth authentication with Google (specifically for Google Calendar).

It's my understanding that I can't reference an external 3rd party library so I have downloaded the google api JS into a static resource, taken from here:
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js

This library is referenced in this sample code from Google:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js#python-3.x

Here's my LWC component that uses platformResourceLoader to load the static resource and call handleClientLoad()

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import gapiLibrary from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/gapi';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class oauth extends LightningElement {

        renderedCallBackCalled = false;

        renderedCallback() {

            if (this.renderedCallBackCalled) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                this.renderedCallBackCalled = true;
        
                loadScript(this, gapiLibrary)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.handleClientLoad();
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('oauth.renderedCallback: error: ' + error);
                    });

            } catch (error) {
                console.log('oauth.renderedCallback: error: ' + error);
            }
        }

      // On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
      handleClientLoad() {
        try {
            // Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state listeners
            gapi.load('client:auth2', function() {

                // Console Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.FQMyBOWbNKQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQ/rs=AGLTcCN26pA1ff1pmP_btrYNbcyVNWJGOQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'https://10724769canadainc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('oauth.handleClientLoad: error: ' + error);
        }
      }

}
```

I've added a CSP policy to https://apis.google.com but I'm getting a CORS error in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.FQMyBOWbNKQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQ/rs=AGLTcCN26pA1ff1pmP_btrYNbcyVNWJGOQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'https://10724769canadainc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Your LWC code looks like it's on the right track, but if you look at the documentation, you need to initialize the API first (see `handleClientLoad()`).

Comment: Thanks @nbrown for the tip - that was helpful. I implemented that function, and added a CSP policy, but when the callback function runs, the console reports a CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.FQMyBOWbNKQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQ/rs=AGLTcCN26pA1ff1pmP_btrYNbcyVNWJGOQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'https://10724769canadainc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any thoughts on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem dumb but when you're creating your "CSP Trusted Site Definition", try removing the "https://" so that it's just "apis.google.com". For some reason, this works for me when invoking resources from LWC, but using "https://" doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your tip - unfortunately that didn't seem to make a difference